# Transforming Normals in Maxscript

Tags: transformation, maxscript, scaletransform

I want to scale normals (Point3 values) so I believe I have to create a scale matrix then use its inverse transpose to scale the normal. This is what I ussually do with 4x4 homogeneus matrixes. However maxscipt uses 3x3 matrix and a 4th row for translation. How can I do the transformation ? Max script allow me to create a scale matrix and invert it. However it says there is no transpose method for matrix3 values.

This is the code that fails:

```
smat = scaleMatrix [1, 2, 3]
smat = inverse smat
smat = transpose smat -- No transpose function for matrix3
p = p * smat
```

Also I wonder if normals change direction even if the surface that they belong to get scaled non uniformly. My intiution says no :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used BigMatrix type in maxscript. However it needs a matrix * Point3 multiplication method. I wrote it aswell.

```
-- constructing the scale matrix
smatrix = bigMatrix 3 3
smatrix[1][1] = sx
smatrix[2][2] = sy
smatrix[3][3] = sz

invert smatrix
transpose smatrix

function bigMulti m v =
(
  local p = [0, 0, 0]
  p.x = m[1][1] * v.x + m[2][1] * v.y + m[3][1] * v.z
  p.y = m[1][2] * v.x + m[2][2] * v.y + m[3][2] * v.z
  p.z = m[1][3] * v.x + m[2][3] * v.y + m[3][3] * v.z

  p = normalize p
  return p
)

-- lets say we want to transform this normal [0, 1, 0]
normal = [0, 1, 0]
normal = bigMulti smatrix normal
```

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix you want to apply is orthogonal, you don't need the inverse+transpose step. Otherwise, you need the transpose of just the 3x3 part:

```
fn transpose3x3 TM =
        matrix3 [TM.row1[1], TM.row2[1], TM.row3[1]] \
                [TM.row1[2], TM.row2[2], TM.row3[2]] \
                [TM.row1[3], TM.row2[3], TM.row3[3]] [0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, if you only wish to scale normals, why can't you scale by a single float or triplet of floats, instead of a matrix?

```
x = [1,2,3]
x*2          -- yields [2,4,6]
x*[2,3,4]    -- yields [2,6,12]
```

For your second question, non-uniform scale is indeed a problem for normals.  Although the Edit Normals modifier will report the same value before and after scaling an object, `$Box001.modifiers[1].getNormal 1 node:$Box001`, in the viewports and render you can see the normals are stretched.  This is one reasons why artists are lectured to never use non-uniform scaling.

On the left is a Box object modelled as a cube, then Edit Normals was applied, then the object was scaled to a rectangle.  On the right is a Box object modelled as a rectangle originally before Edit Normals was applied.  The normals look different in the viewport, and the shading is different in both the viewport and rendering.

[image]

Comment: [link](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/mathematics-physics-for-computer-graphics/geometry/transforming-normals) this explains why I use a matrix for transforming normals. However you are right in a sense. Inverse transpose of scale [sx, sy, sz] should be [1/sx, 1/sy, 1/sz]. This would be much more efficient.